# Likes is missing in Blog site under SharePoint Online Communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-column, blog, communication-site, like

I am using SharePoint online communication site Collection.

I have created a blog site as a sub-site under communication site. I can see comments option is available. But **Like** option is missing.

While digging deeper I found that below **site columns** are missing on communication site collection which are being used for **Like** in blog site:

- Number of Likes
- Number of Ratings
- Rating (0-5)

Does anyone else faced this problem? Is there any solution to enable **Like** option for blog sub-site under communication site collection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it working if you create a modern team site as a site collection and then creating a blog site as a subsite??

Answer (score 1):

The rating feature is not available on communication sites, it is by default.

You can use PowerShell cmdlets to activate it, detailed information, you can refer to the [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Communication-Site-Document-Library-Rating-Settings/m-p/87968).

In addition, there is a user voice about this feature, you can vote [it](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/33237925-modern-page-ratings).